# Bokeh vbar arguments sequences not same length?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a .csv with the following format that I load into a data frame:

```
version, add, subtract, divide, multiply, mod, exp
1.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1.2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

I format the data so it is in a dict:

```
{
'version' : [1.0, 1.2, 1.3]
'add' : [1, 1, 1]
'subtract' : [2, 2, 2]
'divide' : [3, 3, 3]
'multiply' : [4, 4, 4]
'mod' : [5, 5, 5]
'exp' : [6, 6, 6]
}
```

I am trying to plot it as a bokeh vbar stack according to the [example found here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacked). Where the x axis is version number over time and each bar is a stacked bar of the sum of each operation for each version.

Here is my code:

```
operations_df = pd.read_csv('the_csv')

# grab versions from first column
op_versions = list(operations_df.iloc[:, 0])

# grab operations from header except version
operations = list(operations_df.columns.values[1:])

data = {'op_verions': op_versions}
# loop through columns appending to dict
for col in operations_df:
    data[col] = list(operations_df[col])

operations_plot = figure(x_range=op_versions, title="Operation Timings")
operations_plot.vbar_stack(operations, x='op_versions' color=Inferno[len(operations)], source=data,
                               legend=[value(x) for x in op_versions])
```

Yet I get the error:

**Keyword argument sequences for broadcasting must all be the same lengths. Got lengths: [3, 6]**

I don't understand where the mismatch is coming from? There are 3 values for each operation and version. I'm sure this is a simple fix and I can't see it from staring at it so long. The only place where there are 6 values is the number of operations, which I give the correct number of colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 is coming from

```
legend=[value(x) for x in op_versions]
```

But the way `vbar_stack` works is to make a `vbar` glyph for each "row" in the stacks. There are 6 operations in each stack, so you need to provide 6 legend names, one for each row. Perhaps you meant to do:

```
legend=[value(x) for x in operations]
```

instead? If I do that (and fix a few other issues in your code, e.g. the column name in the data source for `x` is `version` not `op_versions`, as well as passing a list of strings to `x_range` to get a categorical axis) then it produces the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Ah yeah the `version` to `op_version` was just a typo writing the question. Thanks though! I got it working!